# Installing the Jasper WAR file manually

Tags: database, war, jasperserver, manual

I am trying to install the jasper WAR file manually for the community edition on a Tomcat server on Unix OS. I am following the steps from the documentation skipping the sample databases.

1. js-ant create-js-db
2. js-ant init-js-db-ce
3. js-ant import-minimal-ce
4. js-ant deploy-webapp-ce

I am able to successfully build the first two steps however step 3 fails. Here is the complete log https://gist.github.com/shruti-palshikar/d3f75f1157028e963a3c

Are there any configurations that are needed prior to this build that I am missing? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done WAR installation on windows machine , see  if this could help you:-

Download the following files:-

1. The WAR file distribution comes in file named jasperreports-server-cp-4.5.0-bin.zip
           in the compressed ZIP format. Download the WAR distribution file from

   http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperserver/files/JasperServer/JasperServer%204.5.0/ .
2. Download the JDBC driver, mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar

   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

After downloading WAR file download Apache Tomcat exe file and install on your system.
There are two way to install JasperReport server by manually or auto, but we are installing it manually.
Before start installing you need to set JAVA_HOME environment variable on your system.

```
       JAVA_HOME="path of jdk folder"

 e.g: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\jdk1.7.0_01
```

To install the WAR file distribution using the manual buildomatic steps:-

1- If you’re using MySQL, place a MySQL JDBC driver in

```
   <js-install>/buildomatic/conf_source/db/mysql/jdbc.
```

2- Start database (MySQL) server.

3- Stop your Application server(Apache tomcat).

4- Copy mysql_master.properties file from

```
    <js-install>/buildomatic/sample_conf
```

and paste it to

```
   <js-install>/buildomatic and rename it to default_master.properties.
```

5- Edit default_master.properties file and change the setting of database server and application server according to your system.

6- Open a Command Prompt as Administrator on Windows and go to buildomatic directory of JasperReport server and run these commands:-

```
a:-  js-ant create-js-db        (Creates the JasperReports Server repository database)

b:-  js-ant create-sugarcrm-db  (Optional) Creates the sample databases
     js-ant create-foodmart-db

c:-  js-ant load-sugarcrm-db    (Optional) Loads sample data into the sample databases
     js-ant load-foodmart-db
     js-ant update-foodmart-db

d:-  js-ant init-js-db-ce                      
     js-ant import-minimal-ce
```

(Initializes the jasperserver database, loads core application data. Running js-ant import-minimal-ce is mandatory. The server cannot function without this data)

e:-  js-ant import-sample-data-ce  (Optional) Loads the demos that use the sample data

f:-  js-ant deploy-webapp-ce       Configures and deploys the WAR file to Tomcat

Start the application serve.

You can see the post  [Here](http://passionfordata.blogspot.in/2012/04/installing-jasper-report-server-from.html)

Comment: Hi Sharad, Thanks. I am following the same exact steps however with postgress every step has been a hassle. Can you look at the log and tell me if you have come across this issue? https://gist.github.com/shruti-palshikar/707e1ee5d44d34561c69

Comment: Actually i never installed Jasperreport server using WAR files on the Linux machine but these are some more information about WAR installation .                                           https://www.dropbox.com/s/w16xbvbx9n5sz9e/Installing%20Jasperreport%20server%204.2.0%20using%20source%20files.docx